# LAMP Error on AWS: Error writing server configuration file ".htaccess"

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm setting up a silverstripe(4) project using LAMP with AWS and I am new to the programming world.
I'm having trouble with after entering the php dev/build.
This error comes up:

```
error-log.ERROR: Uncaught Exception Exception: "Error writing server configuration file ".htaccess"" at /var/www/alsoherdaughter/vendor/silverstripe/assets/src/Flysystem/AssetAdapter.php line 157 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Error writing server configuration file \".htaccess\" at /var/www/alsoherdaughter/vendor/silverstripe/assets/src/Flysystem/AssetAdapter.php:157)"}
```

Not sure what I have done wrong. I have looked about for information/resolutions but not having much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to (temporarily at least) solve any permission issue with:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/alsoherdaughter/ -R
```

(in a Linux terminal)

I mentioned *temporarily*.  If you don't have ownership to the items at hand, it's possible the above `chmod` will be overwritten again by some other process operating by someone else.

You might be able to permanently solve it with:

```
chown /var/www/alsoherdaughter/ YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
```

Comment: Thank you :)i s there anyway to permanently solve it?

Comment: @EmmaKevern Hi!  Yes, you should be able to permanently solve it with `chown`, I've updated my answer with the code.

Comment: Please mark this answer correct if it helped, so that others with the same problem can see the solution.  Thank you!